# 3 W Power LED without heatsink (350 mA)

Tags: led, surface-mount, heatsink, high-power

Can I use this [Prolight Opto PK2N](https://www.tme.eu/Document/1b0152982c3737cf6fde2c395e330265/PK2N-3LxE-Rx.pdf) LED at 350 mA without a heatsink?

Comment: Didn't check the datasheet but just based on the size I'm going to say no. It's rated for 3W power so that probably means about 1W of light plus 2W of heat. 2W of heat in a 3x3 millimetre package is going to get pretty damn hot, probably too hot.

Comment: Note that a heatsink doesn't have to mean one of those aluminium blocks with fins. You just have to have somewhere for the heat to go - maybe it can spread out through your circuit board.

Comment: While this may further complicate things, it might be possible to "relocate" the heat using a copper heat pipe like [these](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/a/advanced-thermal-solutions/round-and-flat-copper-heat-pipes).  Then it becomes a matter of cooling the pipe, but at least it's some distance away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From page 2 of the datasheet: "Please do not drive at rated current more than 1 second without proper heat sink."

From page 19 of the datasheet: "The slug is is not electrically neutral. Therefore, we recommend to isolate the heat sink."

They are assuming that you have some form of heat dissipation.  The datasheet unfortunately does not give you any detailed information about substrate or pour area but running this thing at 350mA is probably going to require some thought.  The thermal slug on your LED is 3x1.3mm; a SOIC-8EP's thermal pad is 3.3x2.3mm - almost twice the area.  The Rth(j-a) of a SOIC-8EP is ~50 C/W; derating curves for your LED *start* at 30 C/W.  They might be assuming you are on an aluminum-clad PCB or have a bunch of thermal vias connected to a machined heatsink.

Again from page 2: "Electrical insulation between the case and the board is required. Do not electrically connect
either the anode or cathode to the slug".  This will complicate things.